# Data is not normal, want to test for interaction too Any non-parametric test?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test, ecology

I have a sample size of $310$ individuals that comprises samples collected along the elevation gradient and at different times. I want to see how the variables differ along the elevation, and with time. I was thinking of a two-way ANOVA test with an interaction. However, I found that my data didn't follow normality and homogeneity of variances (I used the Barlett test, and Shapiro test, and also checked visual representation in the Q-Q plot, log transformation, etc). I then went for the non-parametric Kruskal-Wallis test but it seemed like it couldn't test for the significance of the effect.

Also, there are some outliers in the data, but I feel that since samples are from different times of sampling, when looking for normality, it is considered an outlier (just an assumption).

Can anyone suggest which test to use if I want to test the effect of the interaction between elevation and time on the response variable? I am doing this in R. Or if there are other tests/models that I should try for this type of analysis rather than analysis of variance?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! $1)$ What would you do if you did have normality? $2)$ What, exactly, is not normal?

Comment: 1) I want to use a two-way anova test and also see the interaction effect of elevation*sampling_time, for which I should have a normal distribution of data or the residuals. Or in there a non-parametric test to do so?
2) I have measured values of photosynthetic efficiency, Fv/Fm, PhiPS2, ETR, etc. measures on plants along an elevation gradient at different times. These values do not show normal distribution.

Comment: Welcome to CV. It sounds like you're looking like some form of robust regression--there are many--, but your description is too vague to provide specific recommendations or guidance.  It would help to know some of the details of your evidence against using Normal-based procedures and to have more information about your analytical objectives.  "Want to use a two-way ANOVA" is not an objective (unless this is for learning about ANOVA).  And your data *shouldn't* look at all normally distributed if ANOVA exhibits an appreciable effect, anyway.

Comment: 1. The assumption that's made in deriving the usual test in two way ANOVA is that *errors* are normal; the marginal distribution of the original variables might be very strongly non-normal when the actual assumptions hold. Many answers on site discuss this. $\,$ 2. ANOVA is at least moderately robust to that assumption. The assumptions that will almost certainly be more of an issue will be heteroskedasticity & spatial/time dependence. $\,$ 3. It would help in giving advice if you describe what kind of thing your response variables are measuring & what you want to learn from the data

Comment: @Glen_b my response variables are photosynthetic yield (PhiPS2), electron transport rate (ETR), etc .
I want to look if these variables differes along the elevation and during the different sampling times.

Comment: I don't know how these are measured; is it the case that both your variables are strictly positive, or at least non-negative? I worry that perhaps be a case where a variable is measured on a log-scale or something.  It would help to explain the variables more in the question. I think regression/glm-like models (maybe non-parametric in the model for the mean) is a reasonable idea, but suitable models for your circumstances will require some thought (and likely some subject matter expertise that most of us won't have). You may need to concern yourself with modelling the two forms of dependence.

Comment: @Glen_b yes the parameters are only positive values.
I tried kruskal wallis but i could not add interaction of elevation*sampling_time.

Comment: You can add an interaction to any form of regression that suits your situation. Robust regression, quantile regression, beta regression, or whatever.

Comment: For variables like those, I'd be inclined to think about gamma models, probably with log-link, though the relevant science (which I am clearly no expert on) should inform the model.

Comment: The issue with choosing such a model, naturally, is that the interaction term means something quite different, so the reasons for assuming conditional linearity of expectation in the first place become important.